# SSRS Report Dataset Parameter format discovery when querying Tfs 2010 SSAS Cube

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, cube, reportbuilder3.0

I'm very new to SSRS and Report Builder, and I'm trying to throw together a simple report that shows data for a single changeset. I've created a different report already that takes date paramaters, and thanks to some lucky googling, I learned that instead of feeding date strings to the report parameters, it was necessary to use expressions such as:

```
="[DATE].[Date].&[" & Format(CDate(Parameters!FromDateDate.Value),"yyyy-MM-dd") + "T00:00:00]"
```

Finding this post was like winning the lottery because I would have never been able to figure that out for myself. Hence, for my changeset report, I figured I could use the following expression for my changeset parameter.

```
="[Version Control Changeset].[Changeset ID].&[" & Parameters!VersionControlChangesetChangesetID.Value + "]"
```

For my report, the VersionControlChangesetChangesetID parameter is just an integer. I got the dimension names by using the "Copy" context menu item in the query designer, assuming that these would be the correct identifiers.

However, I get the following error when running the reoprt:

```
The Value expression for the query parameter ‘VersionControlChangesetChangesetID’ contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format. (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)
```

I have two questions about this.

- Why isn't the expression I wrote working?
- How can I learn better how to format these values, and how they're formatted inside the cube, so that I'm not just guessing when I run into these formatting errors?

Thanks!